# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int?' and 'string'

Tags: c#, linq

I have this line of code :

```
Ages = m.RelatedMultipleWorks.Count == 0 ? 
       m.RelatedLook.Age: m.RelatedLook.Age.ToString() + " | " +
                          m.RelatedMultipleWorks.
                            Select(z => z.RelatedLook.Age.ToString()).
                            Aggregate((current, next) => current + " | " + next)
```

This whole line is giving this error :

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int?' and 'string'
```

I can't understand why I'm getting this error. How can I get rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: Just add a `ToString` after the first `m.RelatedLook.Age`.

Comment: What type would you like `Ages` to be? `m.RelatedLook.Age` is an `int?` while `m.RelatedLook.Age.ToString()...` is a `string`.

Comment: In one and the same part of the expression you're once assigning an `int` and a `string` depending on a condition, which could not be possible. You shall either add `.TosTring()` to the first age or remove it from the second. Depends on what type your `Ages` is of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ternary operator expects both outputs to be of same type. Use the following:

```
Ages = m.RelatedMultipleWorks.Count == 0 ? m.RelatedLook.Age.ToString(): m.RelatedLook.Age.ToString() + " | " + m.RelatedMultipleWorks.Select(z => z.RelatedLook.Age.ToString()).Aggregate((current, next) => current + " | " + next),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `m.RelatedLook.Age` is presumably an `int?`, but the result of the secondary ternary expression is a `string` due to `.Aggregate`.

`Ages` (presumably) expects an `int?`; the second half of the ternary cannot be implicitly converted to `int?`, so the compiler yells at you. This is assuming that `.Ages` is a `int?`, otherwise you should `.ToString()` the result of checking `m.RelatedLook.Age`.

Sounds kinda smelly to be storing `Ages` as a string, though - consider maybe using `IEnumerable<int>` instead?

I originally approached this answer trying to explain that perhaps the `Ages` type was incorrect, but I should explain that this is occurring because the ternary cannot resolve to both string *and* int? because those types are not equivalent. Just `ToString`ing the first age would fix the compiler error.

Comment: Actually the issue is that the two parts of the conditional operator do not match and do not have an implicit conversion in common.  Once that's fixed there might also be a conversion problem to whatever type `Ages` is, but that's not what the error message means.

Comment: That's what I meant to imply, but I didn't explain it very well. I'll add that in; thanks.

Comment: Yes, I want to store `Ages` as a string, why should I need `IEnumerable<int>` for that? Thanks.

Comment: You can store it as a string if you want, but something feels "off" to me about wanting to store what is, essentially, a list of integers as a pipe-separated string.